# Informatica mapping creation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to create an Informatica mapping which can sort data and rank it. There are two tables in two different application so directly I cannot join them in SQL. Both has huge data so need to take care of the performance also. Senario could be like below-

There are two tables Department(DEPT) and Employee(EMP).They have 1(DEPT):M(EMP) relation. Department table has columns (Row_id, DeptNm, Created_date),Employee table has columns (Row_id, EMPName, Emp_num, Par_row_id (FK to DEPT.row_Id),Salary)

For a perticular Department sort data as per employee's decreasing salary and rank it. Data should come in text file as below -

DeptNm|EmpNm|Salary|Rank
Finance|Vikram|200000|1
Finance|Uttaam|150000|2
Finance|Rajeev|100000|3
ITDPPT|Balaajii|150000|1
ITDEPT|Harsha|120000|2
ITDEPT|Weeniji|100000|3

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Are you facing any particular problem in creating the mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a joiner transformation to join the department and employee tables. Then use a sorter and rank transformation to rank the rows.